# Motion blur in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blur, motion-blur

How would I add motion blur to a cycles render scene? I have tried looking for youtube tutorials and using the vector blur node but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable motion blur in the properties window:

[image]

Be ready to increase the number of samples as well when you use motion blur.

For more information on all of the many options for motion blur please read the bmanual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/motion_blur.html