# VSE How to blur a rotating tire after rendering?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, compositing-nodes, blur, motion-blur

I have a sequence of images that show a car tire from a single camera view point with the tire at different angles of rotation. The images are similar to the picture below. If the images are animated, one after the other, the tire rotation does not look good. If there any way to fake the rotation and add blurring?

In Photoshop there appears to be a rotating blur filter ([photoshop radial filter](http://www.automotiveillustrations.com/tutorials/photoshop-tutorial-radial-blur-filter.html)) Is there something similar in Blender? Is there another open source tool that can do this?

[image]

Comment: You need to use [motion blur](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71380/motion-blur-in-cycles)

Comment: Thanks, however motion blur during 3D rendering is not an option. Using motion blur in VSE did not give the desired effect. A method to do this exclusively in VSE or VSE and compositor is being requested. .

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10895/fake-motion-blur-on-video-footage-using-compositor

Comment: Isn't there some motion blur already in your footage?

Answer (score 3):

A way to fake motion blur would be to mix the same animation with a slight offset:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is part of the answer. However, the tire is rendered at an angle and has an ellipsoidal shape in the image. Simply rotating does not get the intended effect.